# Unable to add credentials in Jenkins when accessed via reverse proxy ( Netscaler)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, reverse-proxy, netscaler

**Background**

We used to access Jenkins via Hostname and port format and never had issues. eg : http://Jenkinsci.company.com:8080.

We had an internal requirement to enable Jenkins access via company Netscaler (https://apps.company.com/).

So new Netscaler context was created and new url :https://apps.company.com/jenkins now **points to** **->**  http://Jenkinsci.company.com:8080. I also added `JENKINS_ARGS="--prefix=/jenkins"` in etc/sysconfig/jenkins.

**Issue**

Initially we couldnt login. As soon as we clicked on login, we used to get redirected to http page. i.e 
https://apps.company.com/jenkins   **->** http://apps.company.com/jenkins.

. So since login was not working, http to https redirection was setup at Netscaler level. Then login worked.

Now we observed we couldn't add credentials in Jenkins.

[image]

Now after adding the credentials, the drop down doesn't show  the newly added credentials.

[image]

I debugged in Browser and could see the below error message.

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://prod.company.com/jenkins/job/test1/job/test/configure' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://prod.company.com/jenkins/descriptor/com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsSelectHelper/resolver/com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsSelectHelper$ItemContextResolver/provider/com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.properties.FolderCredentialsProvider/context/test1/addCredentials'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I also compared the network messages of adding credentials via Netscaler and directly via host and they look same except in success scenario there are couple of more steps executed.

**Success**

`Request URL: http://Jenkinsci.company.com:8080/jenkins/descriptorByName/com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl/checkId?value=&$provider=com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsSelectHelper%24ItemContextResolver&$token=test`

`Request URL: http://Jenkinsci.company.com:8080/jenkins/descriptorByName/com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl/checkId?value=asdad&$provider=com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsSelectHelper%24ItemContextResolver&$token=test`

`Request URL: http://Jenkinsci.company.com:8080/jenkins/descriptor/com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsSelectHelper/resolver/com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsSelectHelper$ItemContextResolver/provider/com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.properties.FolderCredentialsProvider/context/test/addCredentials
Request Method: POST`

`Request URL: http://Jenkinsci.company.com:8080/jenkins/job/test/job/tess/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig/fillCredentialsIdItems`

**Failure**

`Request URL: https://prod.company.com/jenkins/descriptorByName/com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl/checkId?value=&$provider=com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsSelectHelper%24ItemContextResolver&$token=test1`

`Request URL: https://prod.company.com/jenkins/descriptorByName/com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl/checkId?value=sdfsr&$provider=com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsSelectHelper%24ItemContextResolver&$token=test1`

Any idea what may be the issue and way to resolve without putting a SSL certificate to jenkins instance?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with Netscaler team and initially we added http to https redirection, but it didn't work.
Then I shared below link with them.

[Jenkins Reverse Proxy setup](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+says+my+reverse+proxy+setup+is+broken)

In our setup, Netscaler was accessed via https ,but Jenkins was accessed via HTTP. So we needed to set "X-Forwarded-Proto" header in Netscaler for the request rewrites.

Initially we set X-Forwarded-Proto" header in Netscaler for the response rewrites and it was not working. Be aware that there are very minimal logs and debugging will be difficult.

Hopefully this helps someone.